# Viewpager gives me the wrong position in android when swipe to another image

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am having a `ViewPager` in my android app,I want to display the particular info with each image that i swipe with the `ViewPager`,But i am getting the wrong info or position inside `ViewPager`, it increments and decrements not properly in position,It first increments by two times,Please help me to solve it,My code is as below:
**code:**

```
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return subcategory.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = DetailsActivity.this;
            ImageView imageView;
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            try {
                int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                        R.dimen.padding_medium);
                imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                area.setText(subcategory.get(position).get(
                        Const.TAG_CATAEGORY_NAME));
                System.out
                        .println("::::::::::::::::INFO INDEX:::::::::::::::::"
                                + position);
                imageLoader.displayImage(
                        subcategory.get(position).get(Const.TAG_BIG_IMG),
                        imageView, options);
                System.out
                        .println("::::::::::::::::IMAGE INDEX:::::::::::::::::"
                                + position);
                opkey1.setText(subcategory.get(position).get("opk1"));
                opkey2.setText(subcategory.get(position).get("opk2"));
                opval1.setText(subcategory.get(position).get("opv1"));
                opval2.setText(subcategory.get(position).get("opv2"));

                ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is default behavior, if you want get right position you can use `viewpager.getCurrentPosition();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ViewPager will preload one(by default) pager,so when the user can swipe smoothly.
See

```
ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)
```

PagerAdapter.instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
the position here won't be equal to the ViewPager.getCurrentItem()

If you wan't to get the current position user swiped,use

```
ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener listener)
```

Comment: This is good answer but the problem is that there are five more calls with every viewpager swipe :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I found the following solution:
Inside the onCreate of the Activity that creates the viewpager, after the creation of the viewpager i have added a new onpagechangelistener and i used the onpagescrolled.

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager2);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if (positionOffsetPixels == 0) {
            //Do something on selected page at position
            mtextView.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1) + " of " + String.valueOf(totalimages) + " photos.");
        }
    }
});
```

I have found these approach somewhere else, i do not remmber, but it is working for me.I hope I am helping somehow.